# Documentation deletion of an important concept/example

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

There was an example that I added as part of Java documentation which I found today as being deleted.

The example was about immutability of strings in Java.

[Strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/109/strings#t=201607222113082714623) (This is already deleted, you can check revisions if you want)

This is a very important string related concept in Java, and because many new java learners get amused by this concept while using Java and thus there should be a mention about it in the documentation.

<strike>1. I did not understand why would someone delete it?</strike>

2. Should there be some process where such important concept/example (or anything related to documentation) being discussed in documentation gets moderator intervention before being deleted?

UPDATE :

Apologies, I wasn't knowing how to check comments for change proposal.

But still would like some discussion on #2.

Comment: [Here's the actual change.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/35404) I believe the users who voted to remove it have explained why they removed it.

Comment: @MikeC actually they didn't remove it, they flagged it so someone sends a draft that actually gets approved by other two users to remove it.... yeah

Comment: @MikeC thanks, (did't know how to look up that comment) and I agree with comment suggested by xwoker, but does it mean that one should completed delete the example rather than improvement?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara I don't think so since, as they pointed out, all strings are immutable but I'm not involved with the Java documentation.

Comment: Downvotes!!! Can someone explain why? Low quality/duplicate question?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara My guess is low quality. You could have checked the revision history yourself and apparently others in the community didn't think you were documenting "an important concept".

Comment: In response to your update, there is a review process. It's during that review process that your example was deleted. Currently, at least three people have to agree it should be removed: the person who wrote the draft and two reviewers.

Comment: @MikeC It would be nice if that page showed comments related to the removal like there are for edits on the main stack overflow site.  Looking at this page, its not clear at all why the edits were made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I'm one of the folks that flagged that for improvements (which led to its deletion).  I'll happily address the second point here:

> Should there be some process where such important concept/example (or anything related to documentation) being discussed in documentation gets moderator intervention before being deleted?

***No!***  Moderators are few in number and not to be necessarily regarded as subject-matter experts in certain languages, even if a few of them are.  We as the community vastly outnumber them, and have demonstrated time and again that we are (chiefly) capable of moderating content ourselves; this is why a lot of us have privileges to close content, and even delete it.

Adding moderators into the pipeline to help with the maintenance of Docs would delay us in getting rid of topics which are superfluous, don't belong, or outright terrible (and I'm not necessarily saying that yours was at most one of those).  Moderators should be able to handle things that we as the community *can't*, and thus far they've demonstrated that they can.

I think that this flow is fine.  I don't see any reason for a moderator to intervene unless [something exceptional has happened](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).